# moshi kotlin non constructor properties not serialized

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a class defined like this:

```
data class Medicalnfo(
            @Json(name = "allergies") val allergies: List<Allergy>? = null
    ): ProfileModel(){
        @Json(name = "has_allergies") val hasAllergies: Boolean = allergies != null && allergies.isNotEmpty()
    }
```

The problem is that `hasAllergies` is not included in the json serialization generated by *Moshi*. How can this be achieved?

Here is the test

```
@Test
fun medicalInfoJsonContainsFlags(){
    val adapter = moshi.adapter(Medicalnfo::class.java)
    val jsonStr = adapter.toJson(Medicalnfo(allergies = listOf())) //value is {"allergies":[]}
    assert(jsonStr.contains("has_allergies"))
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the KotlinJsonAdapterFactory. This is working as intended. You may want to create a custom adapter.

Comment: @EricCochran why is it an intended use. Every project is different. I have a need for `val`s to be serialized. There should be support for it instead of writing custom adapters.

Answer (score 2):

If you make `hasAllergies` as var it will work

```
data class Medicalnfo(
            @Json(name = "allergies") val allergies: List<Allergy>? = null
): ProfileModel(){
     @Json(name = "has_allergies") var hasAllergies: Boolean = allergies != null && allergies.isNotEmpty()
}
```